# Email HTML border over content, not cell?

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:2px solid #ffffff; padding: 8px 10px;  border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;  text-decoration:none;">
    <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;">
      <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="google.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none; " title="Book Appointment">
        <span>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT<br> 
          TO VISIT US TOMORROW</span></a>
    </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

No matter where I add the styling for border, it always wraps the entire cell, not the cell **content** itself.

Here's how it is with the code:

[image: SE1]

If I add it on the span element, it breaks the border entirely, like this:

[image: SE2]

Here's how I need it to be:

[image: SE3]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't run code on jsfiddle or SO snippet, pls check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward and will work consistently across all email clients.

**Single line of text**:

```
<table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="" style="margin: auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <h3 style="margin: 0;"><a href="#" style="border: 2px solid #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; text-decoration: none; padding: 20px 30px; color: #ff0000; display: block; letter-spacing: 2px;">Book An Appointment<br />To Visit Us Tomorrow</a></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Two lines of text**:

```
<table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="260" style="margin: 0; border: 2px solid #ff0000;">
  <tr>
    <td style="background: #222222; border: 8px solid #222222; text-align: center;">
      <div style="padding: 10px 15px;">
        <a href="#" style="background: #222222; border: 1px solid #222222; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; display: block; letter-spacing: 2px; mso-line-height-alt: 22px;">Book An Appointment To Visit Us Tomorrow</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unless you need the `<h3>` for screen readers, I suggest removing it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems to be working indeed, but only Outlook separates the borders for them it seems. I'll see if I can figure that one out myself.

Comment: @Rain My apologies. I forgot Outlook does that to an href with two lines of text. So I revised my answer and tested it in Litmus. The two lines of text gets Outlook much closer to looking like the way you want it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of solution for your problem:
one is to add a div around your cell content as follows:

```css
table {background: black}
.contour {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 10px auto
}
```

```html
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="border:2px solid #ffffff; padding: 8px 10px;  border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;  text-decoration:none;">
        <div class="contour">
          <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;">
            <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="google.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none; " title="Book Appointment">
              <span>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT<br> 
                TO VISIT US TOMORROW</span></a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Another one is to use the `a` element as block around your text

```css
table {background:black}
a {
  display:block; 
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:2px solid #ffffff; padding: 8px 10px;  border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;  text-decoration:none;">
    <div class="contour">
      <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;">
        <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="google.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none; " title="Book Appointment">
          <span>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT<br> 
            TO VISIT US TOMORROW</span></a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: div's don't work properly across all email clients (outlook ignores `display block` and `inline-block` from divs). The `a` element might work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Put the border on the `h3` and make it `inline-block`

```css
td {
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 8px 10px;  border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;  text-decoration:none;">
      <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;">
        <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="google.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none; " title="Book Appointment">
          <span>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT<br> 
          TO VISIT US TOMORROW</span></a>
      </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't style the table, style the content, and simplify your markup:

```
    <td>
        <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="google.com"
 style="display:inline-block;border:2px solid #ffffff; padding: 8px 10px;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;" title="Book Appointment">
    BOOK AN APPOINTMENT<br> 
    TO VISIT US TOMORROW</a>
    </td>
```